# Compiler error with unordered_map when used in template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Since my example is somewhat complex, I have put a sample here that demonstrates the error (Code will be inlined below as well):
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a426995302bda656

```
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

enum class DeliveryMethodType
{
  POST_MASTER,
  BUBBLE,
};

class IDeliveryMethod
{
};

class BubbleDelivery : public IDeliveryMethod
{
};

template<typename Key, typename Interface>
class GenericFactory
{
public:

   using FactoryMethod = std::function<std::unique_ptr<Interface> ()>;

   static Key const& Register(Key const& key, FactoryMethod creator)
   {
      s_factoryMethods.insert({key, creator});
      return key;
   }

   static std::unique_ptr<Interface> Create(Key const& key)
   {
      std::unique_ptr<Interface> obj;

      auto it = s_factoryMethods.find(key);
      if (it != s_factoryMethods.end())
      {
         obj = it->second();
      }

      return obj;
   }

private:
   static std::unordered_map<Key, FactoryMethod> s_factoryMethods;
};

template<typename Key, typename Interface>
std::unordered_map<Key, typename GenericFactory<Key, Interface>::FactoryMethod>
GenericFactory<Key, Interface>::s_factoryMethods;

using DeliveryMethodFactory = GenericFactory<DeliveryMethodType, IDeliveryMethod>;

static auto key = DeliveryMethodFactory::Register(DeliveryMethodType::BUBBLE, []() {
      return std::unique_ptr<IDeliveryMethod>(new BubbleDelivery);
});

int main()
{
}
```

My design goal here is to create a generic static factory class. Each translation unit will (at static initialization time) invoke the `Register()` method for a specific specialization of `GenericFactory` for the desired key and factory method types.

I'm getting the following compiler error, which I'm not sure how to resolve.

```
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::hash<DeliveryMethodType>'
```

I imagine perhaps that my template trickery is failing here and I'm not doing something right. Can anyone help identify the issue here? Thanks.

Comment: Successfully compiled with c++14.

Comment: @MaxFomichev That can't be possible since my coliru link is using `-std=c++14`

Comment: Why are you sure? `bash-3.2$ c++ -c -std=c++1y ./main.cpp
bash-3.2$ c++ -v
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix`

Comment: sorry for formatting in my previous message. Your code is successfully compiled by clang 3.5. But, probably, it's c++17 extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key type for an unordered container needs either a specialisation of `std::hash` defined for it, or a custom hash function provided to the container.

Since your container is in a template, with a generic key, it's tricky to provide a custom function; so provide a specialisation, for example:

```
namespace std {
    template <> struct hash<DeliveryMethodType> {
        size_t operator()(DeliveryMethodType x) const {
            return hash<int>()(static_cast<int>(x));
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary (or even legal) to insert the hash specialization into the `std` namespace? Or can I put it in my own namespace and rely on ADL?

Comment: It's necessary because the default hash type is `std::hash<T>` (although you could specify your own type, and override that for every key type you want to support, if you prefer). It's legal to declare template specialisations in `std` as long as they involve a user-defined type. ADL only works on functions; `std::hash` is a class template.

Answer (score 0):

[unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) has a default third parameter which is the hasher for the class contained in the container. Sometimes there is a default implementation of this, eg. for `int` or `std::string` - if not, you have to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

For `unordered_map` you have to provide a hash function for you user defined key-type either by providing a implementation of `std::hash<DeliveryMethodType>` ob by providing your own hash-function as an constructor argument to `unordered_map`.